# How to calculate the expected value of a given distribution in SAS

Tags: sas, expectations

For example, gamma(2,3) is given. Is there any function in SAS like ExpectedValue("Gamma",2,3) to give the expected value of the distribution. I have googled for a while and no satisfactory  answer found.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. 
Given your particular example, the solution is

```
Mean_Gamma = 2 X 3;
```

If your only interested in the Gamma function you make your own function using PROC FCMP or you could simulate a distribution and calculate the average.

Comment: Yeah, I think I have to compute it by a formula.